# Tcpdf multiple bookmarks on single page

Tags: php, tcpdf

Is it possible to have PDF with multiple Bookmarks on one page? I have a page with multipe tables, and each table need to be bookmarked. These tables may increase and go on next page.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation supports explains how to do this [here](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_015.phps).

The syntax is as follows:

```
// Bookmark($txt, $level=0, $y=-1, $page='', $style='', $color=array(0,0,0))

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Bookmark('Paragraph 1.1', 1, 0, '', '', array(0,0,0));
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, 'Paragraph 1.1', 0, 1, 'L');
$pdf->Bookmark('Paragraph 1.2', 1, 0, '', '', array(0,0,0));
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, 'Paragraph 1.2', 0, 1, 'L');
```